# Jackson deserialize List<abstractClass> of classImpl objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an abstract superclass A
I have several concrete sublasess B,C,D

On the serialize side I do this:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
D d = new D();
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```

No problems. I want to now deserialize this.  I understand that I cannot instantiate an abstract class so How is this done?

This does not work:

```
list = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<List<A>>() {});
```

EDIT:  I added this to my abstract superclass: (Still no luck)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public abstract class A {
```

EDIT AGAIN:  I am now getting this error:

```
Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id
```

Looking at the JSON, and the @class is NOT there.  How do I make it be there?
I tried:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=B.class)
public class B extends A {
```

But that did not work.  Any examples of this? How do I tell the object mapper to use my annotation for the class?  Any example for this would be great.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) will help.

Answer (score 0):

You did it properly, but `Jackson` does not checks elements in collections. Please, see my answer for this question: [Error serializing Typed collection with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103451/error-serializing-typed-collection-with-jackson/22118540#22118540). You have to use special collection, for which `Jackson` will use custom serializer.

Simple usage:

```
List<A> list = new JacksonList<>();
list.add(new B());
list.add(new C());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(list);
System.out.println(json);
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<A>>() {}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It seems I have a much bigger problem.  I do: new B(), add some stuff, then writeValueAsString, and I see that the @class is not being added to the JSON.  SOmething else is horribly wrong...

Comment: Could you update your question and provide more information (example source code, result JSONs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

A common work-around for issues with Java Type Erasure (unfortunately problem is more related to this than Jackson) is to use custom sub-type like:

```
public class AList extends ArrayList<A> { }
```

and pass this; it ensures that enough type information is available for serialization and deserialization (since problem is that serialization almost always succeeds as type is available from Objects; not so for deserialization).

And besides this, there is the question of mapping from abstract type A to subtype(s).

If you only had a single implementation, you could use `SimpleModule` and method `addAbstractTypeMapping(A.class, B.class)` to indicate default implementation to use.

But if you need other subtypes, you do need to annotate `A` with `@JsonTypeInfo`, and either make it use Java classnames or specify type names for sub-classes using `@JsonTypeName` (plus `@JsonSubTypes` in base class to let Jackson find them).

Comment: Let's say I annotate A with @JsonTypeInfo like I did in my example. Can you give me a specific example of how to do B using Java Classnames please?